# How do reference a nuget package in a PowerShell 6 module

Tags: powershell, powershell-v6.0

I installed a package using `nuget` in PowerShell:

```
PS > install-package gudusoft.gsqlparser -source https://www.nuget.org/api/v2
```

Which installed DLL in this location:

```
/usr/local/share/PackageManagement/NuGet/Packages/gudusoft.gsqlparser.3.2.6.5/lib/netcoreapp2.0/gudusoft.gsqlparser.dll
```

I referencing the DLL in the module's manifest (`psd1`):

```
RequiredAssemblies = @('gudusoft.gsqlparser.dll')
```

When I load the module that uses the DLL, I get an error:

```
PS > import-module pssqlparser                    
import-module : Could not load file or assembly 'gudusoft.gsqlparser, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I can probably load the assembly directly:

```
Add-Type -Path '/usr/local/share/PackageManagement/NuGet/Packages/gudusoft.gsqlparser.3.2.6.5/lib/netcoreapp2.0/gudusoft.gsqlparser.dll'
```

Another option, I suppose, it to add the `Packages` folder to the `$PATH`.

Is there an idiomatic way to address this issue in PowerShell?

Comment: You can just unzip package and copy dll to your module folder. no need to run install-package. This works just fine for me